# Select *Latest* Grade Information for every Student

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
STUDENT        GRADES
----------     ----------
id             id
name           person_id
address        date
city           test_name
phone          grade
```

Each Student will have several entries in the Grades table.  I am wondering if it is possible using SQL (Postgres) to select all students along with their *latest* grade information.  I basically want a result table that looks like the following, where date, test_name, and grade are for the latest result (by date).

```
LATEST_GRADES
----------------
id
name
address
city
phone
grade_id
date
test_name
grade
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT: ADDED SOLUTION QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM
  students s
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (person_id) person_id, date, test_name, grade
      FROM grades
      ORDER BY person_id, date DESC) g
    ON s.id = g.person_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The clause you're looking for is "[DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)". With it you can easily do the query without subselects and multiple scans of the same table.

In docs, please notice the **ON** part of "DISTINCT ON".

Comment: This one actually worked great for me.  I posted the solution query at the end of the question.  Some of the other double query solutions took around 20+ seconds. After trying the DISTINCT ON method, I got it down to 3+ seconds.

My 'Grades' table actually has 50,000+ rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think Postgre supports windowing functions, so you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM person p
  JOIN grades g ON grades.person_id = p.id
 WHERE row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY g.person_id ORDER BY g.date DESC) = 1
```

Edit: Apparently windowing functions are not supported in the where clause (should've known this since it makes sense). This is, however, not an unsolvable problem:

```
SELECT *
  FROM person p
  JOIN (SELECT person_id, <other_fields>, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn FROM grades) g
 WHERE g.rn = 1
```

Check the execution plan, though, if your data is large.

Comment: Yes, as of v8.4 windowing functions are supported.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me.  "Window functions are not supported in WHERE clause".

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with Postgres, I do a lot of this kind of thing at work with Oracle. Perhaps the query below will be of help.

```
select p.id,
       p.name,
       p.address,
       p.city,
       p.phone,
       g.date,
       g.test_name,
       g.grade 
from person p, 
     grades g
where p.id = g.person_id 
  and g.date = (select max(g2.date) 
                     from grades g2
                     where g2.id = g.id
                )
```

Comment: This works, but takes upwards of 20 seconds, which might not be too great for a webapp.  I'm looking at my indexes now to see if I'm missing something. :)

Comment: @PKKid - I see depesz's DISTINCT ON solution worked for you, and was much quicker. I do wonder, though, if even the 3 second execution could be made even faster with some creative indexing. I may have to give Postgres a try in my next personal project. DISTINCT ON is a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
S.id, 
S.name, 
S.address, 
S.city, 
S.phone, 
G.id as grade_id, 
G.date,
G.test_name,
G.grade

from
   Grades G,
   Student S, 
   (select S.id as studentid, max(date) as latest_grade_date  
    from student S , grades G where s.id = g.person_id) Q
WHERE
   G.person_id = Q.studentid
   AND S.id = Q.studentid
   AND G.date = Q.latest_grade_date
   AND S.id = G.person_id
```

Comment: But the other way looks better